# Is it possible to add an image to the background under a header background image?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image with opacity set to opacity: 0.2; to the main body of my site.  I already have one background image in my header but every attempt to add one in the body between the header and footer only pushes the content down the page and my main body content is pushed into the footer area.

I am new here so any help will be great.  I am willing to post my code here if necessary.

This is the code I have

```
.background-img {
  background-image: url(img/background-scott.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  opacity: .2;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The above class was set to the main div outlining the entire section of code.  The section tag has the same effect...

Thank you

Comment: post your html?

Comment: I could post the site live for now, but there are too many lines of code to post here.

Comment: I posted my site live for the time being.  The URL is http://www.dsjw71sitedesign.com.  I want to put in a background image on the right side of the template section. Below the header and above the footer...

Answer (score 0):

You can add that background image to body or any container that is parent of your header.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/800x400);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  opacity: .2;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>

<header></header>

</body>
```